# delete selected entry in CheckedListBox

Tags: vb.net, checkedlistbox

Good day!
so delete all the ticked entries from CheckedListBox

```vb
  For Each item In CheckedListBox1.CheckedItems.OfType(Of String)().ToList()
            CheckedListBox1.Items.Remove(item)
        Next item
```

Tell me how to delete the selected entry in the CheckedListBox?

[image]

in the picture the record with the name 3 is highlighted. Is it possible and how to delete it without putting a check?

Comment: Really? You know that you have to use the `CheckedItems` collection to remove the checked items but you can't for the life of you work out how to remove the selected items? You haven't really thought that through and you almost certainly haven't read the documentation for that class. If you haven't read the relevant documentation then you haven't really tried to solve the problem yourself, so it's too soon to be asking a question.

Comment: BTW, while it will work, you really shouldn't be calling `OfType(Of String)` there. Unless you're filtering by type, `OfType` does unnecessary work. Also, you only need `Object` references so `String` is unnecessarily specific and won't work if you didn't add `Strings` in the first place. Use `Cast(Of Object)` instead.

Comment: @jmcilhinney [IEnumerable<TResult> OfType<TResult>](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,1020) -- [IEnumerable<TResult> Cast<TResult>](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,1031)

Comment: @Jimi, I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to tell me. Maybe just say what you think is wrong with my comment. `OfType` is for filtering by type, but there's no filtering being done here. `Cast` is for turning an `IEnumerable` into an `IEnumerable(Of T)`, which is exactly what's being done here so is exactly what should be used here. Casting as type `String` will work if the items are `Strings` but they are being used as `Objects` so that's all that is required. In actual fact, if the items weren't `Strings` then `OfType` would actually filter out all the `CheckedItems`. What's incorrect?

Comment: @jmcilhinney No *right* or *wrong*, just info. Related to *OfType does unnecessary work* here. -- Cast<> can throw, OfType<> skips (considered *safer*, but you may want to throw instead, So, it depends).

Comment: Yes, `Cast` can throw and that would be exactly what you want if you intend to loop through every item. Like I said, the items are being used as `Object` references so `Cast(Of Object)` should be called, so there can't be an invalid cast. One should know what they have populated a list with so if one tries to cast as a type other than that, I would think that an exception being thrown to alert you that you've done the wrong thing rather than silently ignoring items not of that wrong type would be preferable. Based on the context, I doubt the OP wants to filter.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple example for

- Removing all checked items
- Removing the current item disregarding the checked state.

Form code

```
Imports System.Globalization

Public Class Form1
    Private Sub RemoveCheckedButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles RemoveCheckedButton.Click

        If MonthCheckedListBox.CheckedItems.Count > 0 Then

            MonthCheckedListBox.CheckedItems.Cast(Of String)().ToList().
                ForEach(Sub(item) MonthCheckedListBox.Items.Remove(item))

            SetActive()

        End If

    End Sub
    Private Sub RemoveCurrentButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles RemoveCurrentButton.Click

        If MonthCheckedListBox.Items.Count > 0 Then
            MonthCheckedListBox.Items.RemoveAt(MonthCheckedListBox.SelectedIndex)
            SetActive()
        End If

    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        MonthCheckedListBox.Items.AddRange(
            Enumerable.Range(1, 12).
                    Select(Function(index)
                               Return DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.GetMonthName(index)
                           End Function).ToArray())

        SetActive()

    End Sub
    Private Sub SetActive()

        ActiveControl = MonthCheckedListBox

        If MonthCheckedListBox.Items.Count > 0 Then
            MonthCheckedListBox.SelectedIndex = 0
        End If

    End Sub
End Class
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub CheckedListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles CheckedListBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
    If isDeleted = False Then
        isDeleted = True
        CheckedListBox1.Items.RemoveAt(CheckedListBox1.SelectedIndex)
    Else
        isDeleted = False
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Dim isDeleted As Boolean = False

```
Private Sub CheckedListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles CheckedListBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
    If isDeleted = False Then
        isDeleted = True
        CheckedListBox1.Items.RemoveAt(CheckedListBox1.SelectedIndex)
    Else
        isDeleted = False
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Private Sub CheckedListBox1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CheckedListBox1.Click

Dim i As String = ""

```
i = CheckedListBox1.SelectedItem

    If i = Nothing Then
        Exit Sub
    Else
        CheckedListBox1.Items.Remove(i)
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    For index As Integer = CheckedListBox1.Items.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
        If CheckedListBox1.GetItemChecked(index) Then
            CheckedListBox1.Items.RemoveAt(index)
        End If
    Next
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33295488)